# Like Button (SEND) Shows the og:metadata info and not the href content (sometimes)

Tags: facebook-like

The site is: http://grantdeb.com

I want to be able to dynamically add meta properties to the Recommend(s) and Send(s).  Right now, it's using the meta og: properties and that is totally NOT what I want.

The LIKE count is also showing incorrectly for each like even though I've pushed the data-href to it like:

```
<div class="fb-like" data-href="http://grantdeb.com/wedding-photographers-hampton-roads/[dynamic id]/Wedding-Photography" data-send="false" data-width="450" data-show-faces="false" data-action="recommend" ></div>
```

BUT - for some reason, once in a while the LIKE / SEND does NOT use the meta properties and correctly shows the correct count AND the correct picture / title I want for the Send.

If you go to our site at http://grantdeb.com look specifically at the "Jasmine Plantation Wedding Photography" (like the 5th post down) you'll see the number of Recommendations is correct, and if you hit the "Send" button at right bottom, it actually uses the correct title and picture we want.

That post is the way we want the Recommend / Send to display.

Why is that happening to some of them and to others it shows our og: metadata?

Answer (score 0):

I can’t exactly see on your site what the problem is (or match your problem description with your site’s content) – but looking at [the URL for the post you mentioned in Facebook debug tool](https://developers.facebook.com/tools/debug/og/object?q=http://grantdeb.com/wedding-photographers-hampton-roads/416/Jasmine-Plantation-Wedding-Photography-Richmond-Wedding-Photographers-Kelly-Tony), it seems that you have

```
<meta property="og:url" content="http://grantdeb.com" />
```

set for all of your detail pages – so that is what Facebook considers the “real” URL for all of your actual posts marked with this tag.

(Can’t tell if this is what you explicitly wanted or not, because your problem description is kinda fuzzy to me.)

Comment: Thanks for your response.

I guess the real question; is there no way to dynamically control the preview image and link for each "LIKE" / "SEND" on the page or will it always use the meta og: property?  I have several "LIKE" buttons on these pages and that, evidently is why they all have the same link and count.

Arghh!  Help.  Thanks.

Comment: Of course they’ll all have the same link and therefor also the same count, if you make them all point to the same URL via `og:url` – if you don’t want them all to point to that one URL, then don’t set `og:url` to that URL on all your individual post URLs …!

Comment: Um - Ok, but if i remove the og:url and og:image, clear the cache and reload the page, the send button STILL shows default app properties and points to our facebook app.  I want it to point to the dynamic link provided for each LIKE.

There has to be a way to control the image and link for each like. 

Thanks, btw for you help thus far.

Comment: I figured it out.  The meta tags on the page referenced int the html tag (in the fb:like) had og:url and og:image meta tags set.  I removed those tags on that page and it's now working correctly.  D'Oh!